# ionicModal Cannot call method 'fromTemplateUrl' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic to display modal, here is my example code:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
    .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope,$ionicModal){
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });

        $scope.openModal = function() {
           $scope.modal.show();
        };
```

When I run my code, I got the error message saying `TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromTemplateUrl' of undefined`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please  create a plunker .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `$ionicModal` after `$scope`

```
  .controller('myController', ['$scope','$ionicModal', function($scope,$ionicModal){
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I really miss look it, always thought of something else...

Comment: I am glad that it helped. :)